# Python Django: how to override validation on MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save multiple checkbox selections on a Charfield, but I cannot bypass the message:

> Select a valid choice. ['...', '...', '...'] is not one of the
>   available choices.

I want to save the selected values with pipe separed values in a single attribute in the database. I have already created "clean" methods for the 2 MultipleChoiceFields, but it seems the error occurs AFTER the clean itself. There is a check if the resulting string is present in the list os possible values. That is what I want to override. Here is the code I'm using:

**estomatologia_form.py**

```
class EstomatologiaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sinais_e_sintomas_locais = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=Estomatologia.TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        label='Sinais e Sintomas locais (marque todas as opções válidas) *',
    )
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['instance'] is not None:
            kwargs['initial'] = {}
            ssl = kwargs['instance'].sinais_e_sintomas_locais.split('|')
            cp = kwargs['instance'].comorbidades_paciente.split('|')
            kwargs['initial']['sinais_e_sintomas_locais'] = ssl 
            kwargs['initial']['comorbidades_paciente'] = cp
        super(EstomatologiaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #OBS: campos para MultipleChoiceField não devem receber esses valores em 'class'.
        #Do contrario os checkbox não são desenhados corretamente
        for field_name in self.fields:
            if field_name != "sinais_e_sintomas_locais" and field_name != "comorbidades_paciente":
                self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs.update({
                    'class': 'form-control form-dinamico',
                })

    def clean_sinais_e_sintomas_locais(self):
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        ssl = self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais']
        self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais'] = '|'.join(ssl)
        return self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais']

    def clean_comorbidades_paciente(self):
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        cp = self.cleaned_data['comorbidades_paciente']
        self.cleaned_data['comorbidades_paciente'] = '|'.join(cp)
        return self.cleaned_data['comorbidades_paciente']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        instance = super(EstomatologiaForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.sinais_e_sintomas_locais = self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais']
        instance.comorbidades_paciente = self.cleaned_data['comorbidades_paciente']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**models.py**

```
...
sinais_e_sintomas_locais = models.CharField(
    blank=False, choices=TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS, max_length=255,
    verbose_name="Sinais e Sintomas locais (marque todas as opções \
    válidas) *",
)
...
```

and here is a printscreen of the error:
[image]

The error message means: "Select a valid choice. drenagem_pus|nenhum_dos_anteriores is not one of the available choices."

Comment: Would be handy for a lot of people if you could translate that error message into English

Comment: Updated! But the error message is pretty much the same as the one on top of the question.

Comment: My bad - didn't notice it there - sorry. Anyway - the error is coming from `choices=TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS` - a combination of pipe delimited multiple choices is not going to be valid... If you're packing/unpacking from that - then you don't want it to be restricted to a certain list...

Comment: Damn, that worked! I've been working on this so long I was overlooking that detail on the model. Thanks man!!!

Comment: Pleased to hear - I've just added that as an answer to close this off...

Comment: For completeness - also added a check that should be run before modifying to a pipe delimited string - adapt as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models - you're using...

```
sinais_e_sintomas_locais = models.CharField(
    blank=False, choices=TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS, max_length=255,
    verbose_name="Sinais e Sintomas locais (marque todas as opções \
    válidas) *",
)
```

... and have `choices=TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS` which'll work in the event of only a single selection, but where you try to pipe delimit multiple selections, they'll fail to match and cause the validation error.

Solution: remove the `choices=` option. Although - you should check that all values are *valid choices* in your `clean_<field>` methods *before* pipe delimiting them and saving it as a `CharField`, eg:

```
def clean_sinais_e_sintomas_locais(self):
    ssl = self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais']
    # Check there are no selections or only valid selections
    if not (ssl or set(ssl).difference(TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS)):
        self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais'] = '|'.join(ssl)
        return self.cleaned_data['sinais_e_sintomas_locais']
    # Error: some individual values weren't valid...
    raise forms.ValidationError('some message')
```

Comment: Very helpful for me Jon, thanks. I somehow assumed that the default validation would handle multiple choice. It's not intuitive if you ask me.

One comment, the condition above 
if not (ssl or set(ssl).difference(TIPOS_SINAIS_E_SINTOMAS)):
will not work as a way to validate. bool(ssl) is only true if there is no data, bool(set....) is only true if there is one or more extra values in the submitted data

so if there is an extra value then it will evaluate
not (false or true)