# MultipleChoiceField only with choices, not with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with a MultipleChoiceField, I can not save it.

Model:

```
 class Companyd(models.Model):

 months_recurrence_options = (
    ("1", "Enero"),
    ("2", "Febrero"),
    ("3", "Marzo"),
    ("4", "Abril"),
    ("5", "Mayo"),
    ("6", "Junio"),
    ("7", "Julio"),
    ("8", "Julio"),
    ("9", "Septiembre"),
    ("10", "Octubre"),
    ("11", "Noviembre"),
    ("12", "Diciembre")
)


   months_recurrence=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=months_recurrence_options, 
   blank=True,null=True)
```

Forms:

```
 class CompanyFormAdmin(forms.ModelForm):

      months_recurrence = 
      forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
      choices=Company.months_recurrence_options)

    class Meta:
      model = Company
      fields = [...
                 months_recurrence
                ...
               ]
```

Views

```
    form = CompanyFormAdmin(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=obj)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

When I save the form, I have this problem:

**{'months_recurrence': [ValidationError(["Escoja una opción válida. ['5', '7', '10'] no es una de las opciones disponibles."])]}**

Answer (score 1):

Since `Charfield` stores only a single choice and you are trying to store multiple in your forms, it gives you a `ValidationError`. You either need to remove `choices=months_recurrence_options` from `Charfield` and check the validation of values with your options in a [different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463976/python-django-how-to-override-validation-on-multiplechoicefield) or to change `Charfield` to [`django-multiselectfield`](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/).